# aspectj and spring roo 'NoAspectBoundException'

Tags: java, android, spring, aspectj, spring-roo

I have a api.jar with some entities compiled with Spring Roo.
I use this library from my android application and see following for every roo generated entity:

*E/dalvikvm(10938): Could not find class 'org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException', referenced from method _Roo_Json.aspectOf
 W/dalvikvm(10938): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2010 (Lorg/aspectj/lang/NoAspectBoundException;) in L_Roo_Json;*

I searched at stackoverflow and found only one answer and it didn't help (suggested to add a *aspectjrt*).

Does anybody has a clue what does it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Spring-Roo uses AspctJ ITD to generate code you need add its runtime libraries as a dependency. <del>But I think that AspectJ is not suitable for Android.</del> *It works*

I found [android-aspectj](https://code.google.com/p/android-aspectj/) library which seems to be a possible way to archive this (I don't try it). Also, this library refers to a [post which explains it](http://blog.punegtug.org/2010/11/adding-aspect-to-android.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, problem was with aspectjrt, it was excluded in gradle build, so aspectj complained about it in the runtime. Works now.

Comment: AspectJ is used a lot with Android, so that part of your answer is just incorrect. The first sentence is correct though.

Comment: Edited to Fix it. Thanks!